# Finding a basis for a particular integer lattice

Tags: number-theory, integer-lattices

The following problem arose in the context of string theory. I hope someone here might provide some guidance or a solution...

Our starting point is:

i) an integer-lattice $L\subset\mathbb R^n$ generated by a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, *i.e.*
$$L=\langle v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_n \rangle=\{m_1v_1+\ldots+m_nv_n: m_i\in\mathbb Z\}$$

ii) a vector $h\in\mathbb R^n$ with $Kh\in L$ for some integer K and K is the smallest such integer. $h$ is also required to satisfy $\frac K2 h\cdot h\in\mathbb Z$, where $\cdot$ denotes the standard dot product in $\mathbb R^n$.

We then consider the lattice
$$\Lambda=\bigcup_{k=0}^{K-1}\{l+kh:\quad l\in L\quad \mbox{and}\quad h\cdot(l+\frac k2h)\in\mathbb Z\}.$$

The question is to find a basis for $\Lambda$.

---

EDIT:
Following WillJagy's suggestion I provide here an explicit 2x2 example for clarity.

Let $L$ be the lattice generated by the basis vectors
$$v_1= \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 0 \end{array} \right],\quad v_2= \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$$
$$L=\{\left[ \begin{array}{c} 2m_1 \\ m_2 \end{array} \right]: m_1,m_2\in\mathbb Z\}.$$
Let also $K=2$ and $h=\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\1 \end{array}\right]$. Then $2h\in L$ and $\frac K2 h\cdot h=2\in\mathbb Z$, so all the requirements are satisfied.

The question is to find a basis for the lattice

$$\Lambda=\bigcup_{k=0}^{1}\{l+kh:\quad l\in L\quad \mbox{and}\quad h\cdot(l+\frac k2h)\in\mathbb Z\}$$
For this example, we have that

\begin{align}
\Lambda&=\{l\in L:\quad h\cdot l\in\mathbb Z\}\ \bigcup\ \{l+h:\quad l\in L\quad \mbox{and}\quad h\cdot(l+\frac 12h)\in\mathbb Z\}\\
&=L\ \bigcup\ (L+h)\\
&=\mathbb{Z}^2
\end{align}
where in the last step we can easily see that $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}^2$ "by inspection", and therefore a basis is $e_1= \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right],\ e_2= \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$, but how do we do this step in the most general case?

---

UPDATE:
The Hermite Normal Form (HNF) might be used in solving this problem but the details still escape me.
For the example above, we start with the basis (in column notation)
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 &0\\
0 &1\\
\end{array} \right),$$
we then add $h=\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\1 \end{array}\right]$ to get
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 &0& 1\\
0 &1& 1\\
\end{array} \right)$$
and the HNF of the above is
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &0\\
\end{array} \right),$$
which is the correct answer. However, I would appreciate it if someone could justify why the procedure works given the weird product constraint in the definition of $\Lambda$.

Comment: Are all $v_i \cdot v_i \in \mathbb Z? $ Are all $v_i \cdot v_j \in \mathbb Z? $

Comment: @WillJagy  Yes! This requirement is part of the definition I use for integer-lattices, (which might not be standard in math :) ). Anyway, I wouldn't mind even if you considered that all $v_i$'s have integer coordinates.

Comment: that is the standard definition, although not the integer coordinate part. Next, your dependencies are not clear, mostly because you use the same letter $v$ for the initial lattice basis for $L$ and then revised for $\Lambda$

Comment: @WillJagy The basis vectors $v_i$ are fixed from the beginning and never revised/changed. All I am saying in the second part is that if we consider the lattice $L'$ generated by the same basis vectors with the exception of the first one that is scaled appropriately, then $\Lambda$ is a sublattice of $L'$. So I didn't manage to find a basis for $\Lambda$ but for a bigger lattice. Can somebody do better than this?

Comment: Sigh. If the $v$'s are fixed, how can you say $h$ can be written as $(1/K) v_1?$ Are you taking all possible $h$ that fit your other requirements, then picking your favorite?????????

Comment: @WillJagy I now see the problem. Ok, let's forget about taking $h=1/K v_1$ (which didn't lead me anywhere anyway). h is *any* vector that satisfies the requirements ii). I agree that h will have some dependence on the starting lattice L and the number K, but it should definitely not depend on the basis $\{v_i\}$. So indeed, out of all the possible h that fit the requirements we just choose our favorite and consider it part of the defining data of the problem. Please let me know if anything is still unclear and thank you so much for spending time on this!

Comment: Could you please work out the entire problem in dimension $2$ and type that in? Perhaps as an answer, it will make less clutter in the question post. I really can't put any construction on your words that gives me a path to follow. A complete  worked example might.

Comment: You might find, also, that completely working out dimension 2 and making a strong start on dimension 3 leads you to a moment when you say "Wait a minute, I know exactly what I want here" and either solve it yourself or make a sharper question here.

Comment: @WillJagy I added an easy example here. I will also follow your advice and try to work it in 2 and 3 dimensions. Thanks for the suggestion.